# Выполнение задания через n времени

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Всем привет. Пишу небольшой сайт и так получилось что мне нужно сделать так.

- Каждый пользователь выбирает интервал времени через которое будет выполняться его задания, интервал фиксирован (1-5-10-30-60 минут)
- По истечению времени пользователю в вк у пользователя поменяется статус в вк.
- Пользователей и заданий будет ровно столько, сколько их зарегистрировано

В двух словах каждый пользователь выбирает время через которое выполнится действие и скрип поменяет ему статус в вк по истечению времени. Вот не могу придумать как это реализовать.

Сперва думал сделать файл с циклом который будет запускаться в кроне каждую 1 мин, получать токен,id и т.п с БД, сверять время и если после последнего обновления прошло уже заданный интервал то выполнит задание, если нет то опять в цикле получит следующего пользователя. Но почему то мне кажется что это плохая реализация да и пользователей может быть неограниченное кол-во. Что посоветуете для данной реализации?

Answer (score 0):

Для данных целей используйте [CRON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).
Создайте отдельную функцию, которая будет проверять текущее время и время, по которому нужно проводить желаемое действие. Вызывайте её с помощью CRON каждое N количество времени.